# Smooth Scrolling interfering with bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I am working on a project and needs smooth scrolling from the navigation bar.
This is the smooth scrolling code:

```
 $(function() {
  // Smooth Scrolling
  **$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])')**.click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

But  I am also using a bootstrap carousel in my website which have right and left controls and have href something like below which changes the image in the carousel:

```
<a class="left carousel-control" **href="#myCarousel**" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
```

Now as I can't stop using the smooth scrolling effect just because of the href problem as when I click on the left or right control in carousel, the whole page tends to go down because of the href function in smooth scrolling and the image in the carousel doesn't change to next one. What could be the possible solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another argument to the line below like this:

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"]):not([href="#myCarousel"])').click(function() {
    //your function
}
```